# build KDtree: non-sensical error during query

Tags: python, scipy, spatial, spatial-index

I'm trying to assess an interpolation scheme, so I'm looking to compare the input points (red) to the resultant grid (blue). I've built two K-D trees looking to find the nearest blue dot to each red dot (with some radius).  My limited understanding suggests that the `query_ball_tree` would provide the results I'm looking for once my trees are built.

```
gridTree = spatial.cKDTree(data=np.c_[np.array(xx.flatten()), np.array(yy.flatten())])
obsTree = spatial.cKDTree(data=np.c_[np.array(bathy['x']), np.array(bathy['y'])])
dist, idx = obsTree.query_ball_tree(gridTree, 2)  # find points in grid that match obs
```

which produces the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/repos/pyObjectiveMapping/operation_FRF_duneLidarDEM_bathy_interp.py", line 211, in <module>
    dist, idx = obsTree.query_ball_tree(gridTree, 2)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

if I try to remove the "extra" argument:

```
    dist, idx = obsTree.query_ball_tree(gridTree)
```

I get the below error (as expected, because it needs both)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spike/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-022d5ab7a46f>", line 4, in <module>
    dist, idx = obsTree.query_ball_tree(gridTree)
  File "ckdtree.pyx", line 1001, in scipy.spatial.ckdtree.cKDTree.query_ball_tree
TypeError: query_ball_tree() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

so the error is not representing the problem effectively.  I've checked and removed all masked data before entering it into the trees.  I've tried removing the reds that were outside of the blue domain, that didn't help (didn't think it should matter, but wanted to check anyway).   I've tried different radii values and had similar results.

[image: spatial representation of 2 data sets]

Comment: It's not the parameters to the function that are causing the problem, it's the return value.  You're receiving a sequence of three or more values, but trying to assign it to two variables.

Comment: What is `obsTree.query_ball_tree(gridTree, 2)`?  Array, tuple, list? length, shape?

Comment: thanks jasonharper do you want to make a response for credit?  i feel like that was pretty dumb on my part!